# Solving an equation involving $x$ both squared and inside a logarithm

Tags: exponential-polynomials, algebraic-equations

Is it possible to solve a function with both exponential and logarithm such as
$$
a x^2 - b\cdot\log(x) = c
$$
in closed form; where $a,b,c$ are constants and $a>0$ and $b>0$?

Comment: Too easy for MO ; try Lambert w-function

Comment: Good question, wrong website. We're about research. You'll get a better reception at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this is one of those interesting cases where it's only clear to those who already know the answer that the question is not suitable for MO.  Many professional mathematicians won't have heard of the Lambert w-function.  If you haven't heard of it then of course you'll have no way of guessing that that's what you need to look up in order to solve equations like this.  Nicely worded as Gerry's comment is, I actually disagree with the implication that this isn't a research question.  I think it's a question that could easily come up in anyone's research... 

Comment: ...and I continue to believe (perhaps swimming against the tide) that MO should welcome questions by researchers wanting to broaden out into fields other than their own.

Comment: @Tom and Gerry, thanks for the positive response. Well it did come up in my research and I thought this would be a good place to ask. I got a closed form solution on Wolfram Alpha but no clue how it was reached. 

Comment: --many professional mathematicians won't have heard of the Lambert w-function.-- Or, more likely, wouldn't consider it elementary. Actually, to handle transcendental extensions with the differentiation rule $dt=\frac{t}{t+1}\frac{df}f$ is possible but somewhat unpleasant...

Comment: I will honestly admit that I laughed at "Tom and Gerry".

Comment: Short explanation. If you substitute $x=\sqrt{t}$ in the equation $ax^{2}-b\log x=c$ you can rewrite it as $-\frac{2a}{b}e^{-2c/b}=\left( -\frac{2a}{b}t\right) e^{-2at/b}$. Since by definition of the Lambert $W$ function $Y=Xe^{X}$ iff $X=W(Y)$ this means that $W\left( -\frac{2a}{b}e^{-2c/b}\right) =-\frac{2a}{b}t=-\frac{2a}{b}x^{2}$. And solving for $x$ you get $x=\left( -\frac{b}{2a}W\left( -\frac{2a}{b}e^{-2c/b}\right) \right) ^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

As @AméricoTavares did in comments, making the problem more general
$$a x^n - b\log(x) = c\qquad \implies \qquad a x^n - \frac bn \log(x^n) = c$$
$$x^n=t\quad \implies \quad a t - \frac bn \log(t) = c\quad \implies \quad t=-\frac{b}{a n}\,W\Big(-\frac{a n}{b}e^{-\frac{c n}{b}} \Big)$$

The solution is reeal if
$$\frac{a n}{b}e^{-\frac{c n}{b}}  \leq \frac 1e$$
Back to $x$
$$x=\Bigg( -\frac{b}{a n}\,W\Big(-\frac{a n}{b}e^{-\frac{c n}{b}} \Big)  \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: This explanation is also in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105696/solving-in-x-involving-both-exponential-and-logarithmic-function#comment272425_105696), by @AméricoTavares (without the substitution of $n$ for $2$).